# How to group data from database by particular column?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following dataset:

```
ToDo_Name      List_ID
-------------------------------
Read book          1
Study English      2
Do excercises      2
Sleep              1
Eat                1
```

I need to group this data by List_ID creating the array like this (and send it as json to frontend):

```
$result = array(
      array("listId" => 1, array('Read book', 'Sleep', 'Eat ')),
      array("listId" => 2, array('Study English', 'Do excercises'))
);
```

I can't understand - should I do this using some SQL query or PHP array methods? Will be happy to hear any advices...

Comment: `select listId, group_concat(ToDo_Name) from yourtable group by listId`

Comment: continuing on @splash58's answer, use `explode` function in php on the `group_concat`'s result string, to convert into array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use group concat ..

```
  select list_id, group_concat(ToDo_Name)
  from mytable 
  group by  list_id
```